# drawable for background view - what type of resource?

Tags: java, android

I'm going to be using

```
setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background)
```

in my onCreate() method.

When I create the XML file with the  and its colors, what type of resource am I creating? "values", "layout"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean what folder? `setBackgroundResource()` takes a drawable, so you would put your resource in the drawable folder. Hence why your example has `R.drawable.background`

Comment: Right. I've created the folder, but when I create the actual xml file - what I'm asking is: eclipse asks me to select what type of resource it is. What do I choose? layout, preference, values, searchable? The root element (i'm pretty sure) is going to be <shape>. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: I don't think it matters what you tell eclipse.. it is just going to auto populate something for you, you can go change it.